# XSLT replacing text in attribute value and text nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, xslt-1.0

I have an XML document that I'm trying to transform and do a string replace of certain values when that value occurs in either a text node or an attribute named *message*. My xsl file is below, but the main issue is that when the replace occurs in the *message* attribute, it actually replaces the whole attribute and not just the value of that attribute, so

```
<mynode message="hello, replaceThisText"></mynode>
```

becomes

```
<mynode>hello, withThisValue</mynode>
```

Instead of

```
<mynode message="hello, withThisValue"></mynode>
```

When the text occurs in a text node like

```
<mynode>hello, replaceThisText</mynode>
```

Then it works as expected.

I haven't done a ton of XSLT work, so I'm a bit stuck here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@message">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'replaceThisText'"/>             
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'withThisValue'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- string-replace-all from http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx -->
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
          select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template matches an attribute, but it doesn't output one.

Note that the value of an attribute is not a node. Therefore, you must use separate templates for text nodes and for the attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'replaceThisText'"/>             
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'withThisValue'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@message">
    <xsl:attribute name="message">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'replaceThisText'"/>             
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'withThisValue'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```