# How to add a dependent folder for a Wix burn bootstrapper exepackage

Tags: wix, burn

I am new to Wix burn bootstrapper so pardon my ignorance.I have a requirement where i need to install a pre-requisite using burn bootstrapper.
The prerequisite is a setup.exe(third-party) which has dependency on files and a folder(containing couple of files).All these need to exists in the root of setup.exe for the setup.exe to run successfully.

example structure--

1. setup.exe
2. samplefile.rsp
3. files(this is a folder which contains files needed by setup.exe)

   1. Data1.cab
   2. Clientruntime.msi
4. anotherfile

Here is what i got so far.

```
    <ExePackage Id="Ingres_Client"
                Compressed="yes"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Vital="yes"
                SourceFile="setup.exe"
                InstallCommand="/r sampleCR.rsp"
                InstallCondition="(VersionNT &gt; v5.1 OR VersionNT64 &gt; v5.1)"
                DetectCondition="Ingres">

    </ExePackage>
```

I tried to include the nesessary files using PayLoad.But i cant figure out how to  add a folder('files' folder) as it is as a requirement for the setup.exe

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `Name` attribute of child `Payload` elements.

```
<ExePackage SourceFile="setup.exe">
    <Payload SourceFile="samplefile.rsp" />
    <Payload SourceFile="anotherfile" />
    <Payload Name="files\data1.cab" SourceFile="files\data1.cab" />
    <Payload Name="files\clientruntime.msi" SourceFile="files\clientruntime.msi" />
</ExePackage>
```

If there are lots and lots of files, it's probably better to just make a self extracting zip archive.

Comment: Thank you Sean of the answer! Your example code really helped me!

Comment: @user2547006 Thanks.  On [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), you should upvote answers that are helpful and accept answers that answered your question by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: If there are many files you can also use heat or paraffin to create the payload xml. For heat you will need to use a xslt transform (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982208/bundle-multiple-support-files-for-wix-burn).