# Deployment of external payload with wix bundle

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bundle, wix3.10

We are using Wix to deploy our application. But for deploying our application we need to first deploy an application which is a prerequisite for our application. And the setup for that application is available to us as an external payload which we will be shipping along with our application setup.
[image: Fig 1: this .exe is the main wix bundle we will be using to install our application. And the setup of prerequisite is inside the folder ”issetupprerequisites”.]

Fig 1: this .exe is the main wix bundle we will be using to install our application. And the setup of prerequisite is inside the folder ”issetupprerequisites\{9BA97839-8D57-467D-8FDF-487966F8A4C2}”.

[image]

Fig 2: this is the setup.exe which we are shipping with our product which needs to be installed as a pre-requisite to our product.

But the problem we are facing is to give the path for that pre- requisite application exe , since that path will be a  relative path because different user will be installing it from different location.

We decided to use a variable called [WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder] but are unable to use that.

[image]

Fig 3: Giving the path for that exe in this way so that we can install the external payload from our wix bundle on any machine , but failing to do so since path is not recognized.

[image]
Fig 4: giving this error.

Please guide us on how to give the path for that external payload exe so that it works on all the machines without any issues.

NOTE: we are using wix version 3.10 for our project.

Answer (score 1):

`Payload/@Name` is not a formatted value, so you're specifying that there is a folder literally named `[InstallFolder]`. It should work if you just use `issetupprerequisites\{9BA97839-8D57-467D-8FDF-487966F8A4C2}\setup.exe`.

Comment: did that got the same error "The system cannot find the file 'SourceDir\issetupprerequisites\{9BA97839-8D57-467D-8FDF-487966F8A4C2}\setup.exe'. "

Comment: That file is required at build time so it can be hashed. That file must be in that path relative to your .wixproj, or you need to use the `Payload/@SourceFile` attribute to specify where it is at build time.

Comment: But if i  give the relative path at build time and at build time it will be successful but what about at run time of the .exe on other systems because my final exe is in different folder and has a different relative path to the setup.exe which i want to install as a prerequisite.

Comment: That's really a different question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29617883/628981.