# Wix bootstrapper and trying to install an exe that has multiple files

Tags: wix, wix3

I am trying to get Wix to install https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/software/CP210x_Windows_Drivers.zip

It is basically an exe that has multiple files and folders that are required for the installation to work.

I have added this this to Bundle.wxs in the Bootstrapper.

```
<Fragment>
<PackageGroup Id="WindowsCP210xVCPInstallerx64" >
  <ExePackage
    Id="WindowsCP210xVCPInstallerx64"
    Name="$(var.PackagePath)\CP210xVCPInstaller_x64.exe"
    DisplayName="CP210x USB to UART Bridge Virtual COM Port (VCP) drivers"
    Cache="no"
    Compressed="no"
    PerMachine="yes"
    Permanent="yes"
    InstallCondition="VersionNT64"
    InstallCommand="/Q /SW /SE"
    RepairCommand="/Q /SW /SE"
    UninstallCommand="/U $(var.PackagePath)\CP210x_VCP_Windows\slabvcp.inf /Q"
    SourceFile="CP210xVCPInstaller_x64.exe">
  </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

However when building I keep getting this error

```
 The system cannot find the file 'CP210xVCPInstaller_x64.exe'.
```

At present I have just added the entire folder that contains the CP210xVCPInstaller_x64.exe and all the other files it depends on into the project.

Comment: Could it be something as simple as you having the `SourceFile` and `Name` attributes the wrong way round? Looks like the value in Name should be the one in SourceFile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a dependent folder for a Wix burn bootstrapper exepackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610793/how-to-add-a-dependent-folder-for-a-wix-burn-bootstrapper-exepackage)